# How to Use Dynamics 365 Channel Integration Framework (CIF) in a .NET C# Windows Application

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm working on a .NET C# Windows application and I need to integrate it with Dynamics 365 using the Channel Integration Framework (CIF). However, I'm not sure how to get started or what steps to follow.

Specifically, I have already obtained an access token for authentication with Dynamics 365. Now, I want to use this access token to interact with CIF to perform various operations.

Can someone provide me with guidance or a step-by-step example on how to use CIF in a .NET C# Windows application? How can I connect to CIF, authenticate, and perform actions like opening forms or accessing Dynamics 365 data within my application?

Any code examples, library references, or documentation links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, this CIF is meant for browser based integration between Dynamics 365 model driven App and Telephony channel. So your direction of developing windows desktop app using CIF may not be the intended use case by Microsoft product team. Pls consult with them as well.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/channel-integration-framework/v2/overview-channel-integration-framework?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422).

> Dynamics 365 Channel Integration Framework is a cloud-to-cloud extensible framework for integrating telephony channels with model-driven apps in Dynamics 365 by using a browser-based JavaScript API library. With this framework, you can integrate any telephony channel into a model-driven app in Dynamics 365, and the framework will act as the interface between the channel and the app.